# How to 301 redirect htaccess with & sign

Tags: .htaccess

From /?act=view&id=NUMBER to URL

examples:

/?act=view&id=1 to http://google.com

/?act=view&id=2 to http://facebook.com/blabla

My code

```html
Redirect 301 /?act=view&id=157 http://google.com
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried?

Comment: `Redirect 301 /?act=view&id=157 http://google.com`

Comment: Please dont post post the code in comments. edit your question.

Comment: Done, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can not manipulate query strings using a **Redirect** directive, you need to use mod-rewrite,

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on

#1)Redirect "?act=view&id=1" to "http://google.com/"#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?act=view&id=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://google.com/? [NC,L,R]
#2)Redirect "?act=view&id=2" to "http://facebook.com/"#
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?act=view&id=2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://facebook.com/? [NC,L,R]
```